# Find a basis for orthogonal complement in R⁴

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

[image]

How do I approach part 2? I found the projection of 1. to be (6,-2,2,-2) but what do I do now?

Comment: What is the definition of the set $W^{\perp}$ and what have you tried ?

Comment: Find a nonzero vector orthogonal to both $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(2,5,0,1)$.  Find yet another nonzero vector orthogonal to both while also being linearly independent of the first.  If it is not immediately clear how to find such vectors, try describing it using linear algebra and a matrix equation.

Comment: That is, for vector $v = (x_1, x_2, x_3,x_4)$, the dot products of $v$ with the two given vectors respectively are zero.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&5&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Find a basis of the solution space.

Comment: Ahhh so the orthogonal complement is just the span of (3,-1,1,-1)

Comment: No... you are missing another vector

Comment: span of {(3,1,-1,1) , (-15,6,1,0)}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For vector $\mathbf v = (x_1, x_2, x_3,x_4)$, the dot products of $\mathbf v$ with the two given vectors respectively are zero.

$$\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&5&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\0&1&-6&-7\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf v &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&15&18\\0&1&-6&-7\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf v &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}$$

Let $x_3 = a$, $x_4 = b$, then $x_1 = -15a - 18b$, and $x_2 = 6a + 7b$.

$$\mathbf v = \begin{bmatrix}-15a - 18b\\6a+7b\\a\\b\end{bmatrix}
= a\begin{bmatrix}-15\\6\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix}-18\\7\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

So $(-15,6,1,0)$ and $(-18, 7,0,1)$ together is a basis.

Setting $a=1, b=-1$ gives $(3,-1,1,-1)$, which is one of the vectors in your basis above.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one could solve the linear system $Ax=0,$ where
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&5&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
$A$ us equivalent to the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&15&18\\0&1&-6&-7\end{bmatrix}$$
which has the solution set $\operatorname{span}\{(-15,6,1,0),~(-18,7,0,1)\}.$

Note that since $\mathbb{R}^{4}=W\oplus W^{\perp}$ and $\operatorname{dim}W=2,$ you get that $\operatorname{dim}W^{\perp}=2,$ as well.